# Slide viewController in navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'd like to use a slide up / down effect to display various viewControllers inside a navigation controller. A few other apps do this like square, and every day. Basically when the app loads, I want to display a base view in the navigation controller. Then slide up another view controller over top of it. When then hit a button in the nav bar, I want to slide that down and show the base controller, all the while retaining the navigation bar, and changing up nav items.

Originally I tried to make this work by showing a modal but that requires using a new nav bar.

Has anyone done this, or knows of a good example that illustrates this UI pattern? Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a navigation controller, its a navigation scheme designed from scratch. You are going to want to look into `UIViewAnimations`.

Comment: It behaves like a regular nav controller otherwise though. Look at the right bar button item. It just pushes a view controller on there.

Comment: OK sorted it with animateWithDuration. Boom.

Answer (score 0):

You could have UIViews in a UIScrollView